# Using fancybox with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, fancybox

I am working on integrating my pre existing website into a RoR framework. So far so good, however I have come to a problem when trying to get fancybox to work.

Simply put I am unsure how to link to the image files and have tried all kind of different variations. For example:

```
<a class="fancybox-image" href="image.jpg"><div class="call-to-action-section" style="margin-top: 5px;">See more</div></a>
```

This is a snippet of code from my html - the href within the anchor tag represents the image that I would like to be loaded into fancybox when the button is clicked, however an error message is given which tells me that the image cannot be found.

Are there any particular prefixes needed on the href?

Comment: check the path of the href="image.jpg" to see if it actually takes you to the image you want. try opening it in a new tab or window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image into the `assets/images`-directory and then you have to reference the image via the `image_path`-helper:

```
 <a class="fancybox-image" href="<%= image_path('image.jpg') %>"><div class="call-to-action-section" style="margin-top: 5px;">See more</div></a>
```

Comment: This didn't work at first, as I wanted the image in a subfolder of the Images folder. However I put it within ""s instead of ''s, ie "folder/subfolder/image.jpg" and this worked. Many thanks

Comment: It does work with subfolders. My guess is, that you prefixed your subfolder with a leading `/`, in which case Rails resolutes the path to `/subfolder/image.jpg`, instead of `/images/subfolder/image.jpg`. Check out the [api-docs for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper#image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

Comment: No I definitely didn't prefix with a /. The default path (ie, your suggestion above) viewed in the browser came up with href="assets/image.jpg". I prefixed this with the path which would lead it directly to the image, but this still didn't work. I don't know why as I'm new to this, but using "folder/subfolder/image.jpg" definitely seems like the way to go...